# scraping data with pjscrape

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs

I was scraping data with cheerio and request.  However, I could not get a data table that was created with the data tables library.  I am now using phantom js and pjscrape.  I went through the phantom tutorials and did the hello world.  I have started the pjscrape tutorials, but do not understand the path:

```
/path/to/pjscrape.js
```

I am using

```
phantomjs pjscrapejs config.js
```

Not sure what the path is supposed to be.  I tried reading an example on the docs but I am not seeing an answer that clears this up.

Answer (score 1):

It's the relative path to the pjscrape.js file compared to where you're running the phantomjs executable from.

If they're in the same directory, then just 'phantomjs pjscrape.js config.js' will do the trick.